# Meteor production and dev environments has different public folders

Tags: node.js, meteor

I notice that DEV ENV on meteor, public folder is under /public.

So I use something like:

fs.writeFile(process.env.PWD + "/public/" + file)

To save files.

On production, I notice that public folder is under /programs/web.browser/app.

So, when I save files on production, it goes to /public but when I try to retrieve them, it tries in /programs and dont find it.

What am I doing wrong? How can I upload to correct folder on DEV or change public folder on PROD?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `public/` folder for the wrong purpose. Its purpose is solely to serve static files *that already exist in the bundle*. If you want to create more files at run-time that should then we serves statically, then you'll need to add your own static route to the router, for which you then can use a folder of your choice.